# Where does Jenkins store config files for "Views"?

Tags: jenkins

I have removed some Jenkins views that listed jobs in categories for me. I keep backup of Jenkins filesystem and I now want to restore these views.

Where are the configurations files for Jenkins views stored on filesystem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The views are stored in the main config.xml file (`JENKINS_HOME` or `jenkins` user home directory).

For my CentOS install, it's in `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`.

Please have a look to the `<views>` section.

Comment: I guess it is more correct to say that `config.xml` is located in `JENKINS_HOME` or `jenkins` user home directory.

Comment: @MaksimSorokin You're right, I'll update my answer :)